# Number of nodes at given depth in binary tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, discrete-mathematics

> Show that there is no comparison sort whose running time is linear for at least half of the $n!$ inputs of length $n$. What about a fraction of $1/n$ of the inputs of length $n$? What about a fraction of $1/2^n$?
>
> - The running time of a specific input is linear if the corresponding leaf node is within a linear distance from the root. Considering a binary tree, the maximum number of nodes within a linear distance from the root is $2^{kn+1}-1$.

How $2^{kn+1}-1$ was reached? just I need an intuitive idea not a proof. this is my notes not an homework or exercises. $k$ and $n$ not defined on it context.

Comment: Please credit the source of all copied material.  Our policy can be found here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9304171/781723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, the maximum number of leaves at distance at most $d$ from the root is obtained when all of these leaves are at distance exactly $d$ from the root. Since there are at most $2^d$ nodes at distance exactly $d$ from the root, this suggests that the maximum number of leaves at distance at most $d$ from the root is $2^d$.

We can easily prove this bound formally using Kraft's inequality, which states that
$$ \sum_{\ell} 2^{-d(\ell)} \leq 1, $$
where $\ell$ goes over all leaves, and $d(\ell)$ is the distance of $\ell$ from the root. Kraft's inequality implies that
$$ 1 \geq \sum_{\ell\colon d(\ell) \leq d} 2^{-d(\ell)} \geq \sum_{\ell\colon d(\ell) \leq d} 2^{-d},$$
from which it immediately follows that there are at most $2^d$ leaves at distance at most $d$ from the root.

---

The text you quote is less sophisticated. It is bounding the number of leaves at distance at most $d$ from the root by the number of *nodes* at distance at most $d$ from the root. Since there are at most $2^e$ nodes at distance exactly $e$ from the root, it follows that the number of nodes at distance at most $d$ from the root is bounded by
$$ \sum_{e=0}^d 2^e = 2^{d+1} - 1. $$

Comment: In your text, $n$ is the input length, and $k$ is an arbitrary constant.